How was MP/M’s time sharing implemented?
MP/M, the multi-user sibling of Digital Research ubiquitous CP/M, implemented time-sharing in a way that appears to be very efficient. Processes don’t appear to see each other’s memory and performance seems to degrade very linearly as you add running programs. How was it implemented?

You usually ran only one at a time and had a key sequence to switch to another.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Not that way at all. Processes could run on (a) multiple terminals, (b) in pure background mode (detached from the console) and (c) even on a single terminal (if set up for multiple processes, certainly the case in much later versions such as CDOS, not so sure about older MP/M) with multiple process switching the processes not-currently-selected would keep running until they needed terminal I/O.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I’ve used both CCP/M-86 and C-DOS, but this is still about the 8-bit predecessor which the question is about

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen all the more so - original MP/M was more about multi user than multitasking, so the key swotching doesn't apply so much

Now I’ve looked it up.  Interrupt switching was optional and its implementation recommended to be delayed until the polled version was bug free. So it could - my bad

Mp/m (reverse engineered?) sources are at http://www.cpm.z80.de/source.html


MP/M [...] implemented time-sharing in a way that appears to be very efficient.

Yes, and the answer is as usual: Due to very minimal overhead
Most data structures were static and with limited size - like 8 banks, 16 terminals, fixed number of (open) files, fixed priorities and so on. In such an environment management can be lightning fast as code length to decide what to do next is short.
Also MP/M systems usually had faster CPU speed than single user systems. On a 2 MHz Z80 it may have been less great, but with 4, 6 or 8 MHz several users could be easy handled. Of course it helped a lot that MP/M usage was mainly text-based with the CPU idling most of the time (*1)

Processes don’t appear to see each other’s memory

They do. MP/M contains no protection, as the underlaying hardware doesn't offer such. The Z80 provides no way to limit memory access to an assigned region; any program can access all memory and I/O. It can access any other program or data, no matter whether application or OS. Likewise a program can freely access all I/O.
Thus banking, if present (*2), cannot add any protection, as a program may of course access and manipulate all ports that manage those banks. But thanks to XIOS no hardware access is needed. A program may simply create a memory descriptor, load its address in BC and call BIOS+33h, BIOS's entry for SELMEMORY (*3).

and performance seems to degrade very linearly as you add running programs.

Again, not really special for a system with defined resources that do not get virtualized. Of course, with a hard disk and swapping it could get slow. Like today, that's easily solved by buying more RAM :))
Nonetheless, it did add overhead. Compared to CP/M, programs did run some 10-15% slower - which was easy caught by using a faster CPU card, as mentioned.

How was it implemented?

Very conventionally.

A straight memory management system working with segments in page chunks (using the mentioned memory descriptors), no complex allocation or reallocation. (*4)
A Loader for absolute (COM) and relocatable (PRL) (*5) code
A lean queue management used for IPC and locking
A flag system for semaphores
XIOS providing a device poll, i.e. a process can wait for an IO to finish.

All of the above is used by a priority driven dispatcher to decide which process comes next in case the actual one runs into time slice end (Flag#1), I/O wait, writing for queue, other flag, etc. pp.
It also helped a lot that CP/M programs were usually very clean (using only OS functions to interact with hardware) as there was no major system (like the PC), setting hardware standards to be (mis)used. With all I/O going through the OS it could very easy catch and manage each task.
As said, very conventional and very simple. Entry-level stuff that can be designed and coded in a weekend or two (*6). Ask if you'd like some specific details.

*1 - Back than wasn't like today with tons of graphics, animated mouse pointers and whatsoever. For most of the time there was barely anything to be done until a key got pressed. That got be forwarded to its program which may act upon it (mostly only inserting it in the field in focus) and maybe output a few bytes to screen. 3 or 4 people using some accounting application or word processing could easy run on a 4-6 MHz Z80. Nowadays even moving a mouse requires more bandwidth than a Z80 had in total.
*2 - MP/M worked quite fine without banking on machines as small as 32 KiB. Okay, not leaving much space, but even there running more than one (small) program.
*3 - Doing such from a non-banked region might be helpful :))
*4 - Keep in mind that for such systems the use case wasn't starting hundreds of programs in random order. Usually one had one or two applications per user, loaded them once and attached/detached(*7) as needed.
*5 - PRL relocation was using a really nifty but unusual relocation algorithm allowing quite fast loading/relocation. If interested, ask another, specific question. I'd love to describe it :))
*6 - I said designed and coded - as usual, debugging may take many more nights :))
*7 - Attach/Detach means connecting and disconnecting a terminal to a running program - think of it like minimizing windows. Or like detach and reattach with Screen under *nix - except that Screen is a far more complex and powerful tool. MP/M really only supports a single full-screen terminal at a time.

*7 is more like attaching and de attaching to screen for those on *Nix systems

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Jo. you're right. Then again, I just doubt anyone will understand this a few years from now - that is if it needs that long :((

Linux systems administrators will at least. Screen is a very useful companion to ssh.

I agree - I know screen exists, even though I prefer tmux.

Based on Wikipedia, it's implemented via bank switching on the 8080/Z80, as these CPUs can only address 64kB.
It means that each program is loaded to run in its own memory bank, and only one bank at a time is switched to be accessible by the CPU memory address window to the banked memory. The OS kernel controls which bank is active, thus defining which program runs.
This way all programs think they run at the same address and can't access memory of other programs.
Technically the 8086 port could achieve the same by using the segment registers of the CPU, but even if all programs get their own segments, a malicious program or one with errors could access other segments, so it could also be using bank switching in hardware.
The 80286 port could use the 16-bit protected mode where a program can only alter its own segment registers if there is need, the kernel can run in privileged mode and switch between different programs by changing the segment registers and how they map the memory.

True, but a 'malicious' program can as well screw Z80 bank switching as the CPU does not provide any protection scheme to hinder arbitrary programs in accessing all I/O ports or memory. Also, MP/M may use bank switching, but does not need to.

@Raffzahn the TPA would be not he very big in a non-banked system :-/

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Never said it will :)) But we were all more contempt back then, weren't we?

@Raffzahn 640 bytes ought to be enough for everybody?!

@Raffzahn: contempt is what I feel for management at the start of the week, content is how I feel at weeks end. I think you meant the latter :-)

This sounds similar to the method used by TSS/8 on DEC PDP-8.

TL;DR Preemptive multitasking at a default 60 Hz
Another answer covered the memory handling for 8-bit systems and 16-bit up through the 80286. By the 80386 the operating system evolved into Concurrent DOS which added support for MS-DOS applications. With the 80386, memory management changed significantly, using the virtual 8086 mode to run each application in a protected chunk of memory. This also made it practical to run IBM PC applications that made direct screen access with the screen memory updates translated into text sent to PC-Mode terminals.
As far as the efficient performance, I am pretty sure all versions used the system timer at a default of 60 Hz for preemptive task switching.
Thanks to the wonderful source archive at http://www.retroarchive.org/cpm/archive/unofficial/source.html I found the smoking gun in MPMLDR/GENSYS.PLM:

  declare default$system$data (256) byte data (

  60,    /* 122-122 # ticks/sec */

Not sure if there were non-US versions that used a 50 Hz timer.
But well-behaved applications would typically be disk or other I/O bound and so the operating system could switch tasks more frequently whenever a task had to wait for something else to happen. This worked extremely well for typical systems I worked on - multi-user accounting, database and similar systems. That doesn't work as well for games (well, except for simple things like text-based adventure programs) or for non-well-behaved IBM PC programs. On a single-user PC an application would often write directly to video card memory (officially never recommended, but OK on an 80386 because the operating system could handle that) but would also simply be lazy and waste CPU time while waiting for user input. Various fixes evolved to handle the CPU wait problem, as otherwise a single ill-behaved application could significantly impact performance of all other users/programs on a large system.

When I was in the University of Maryland I took CMSC 412 - Operating Systems in 1986 (I think it was 1986, it has been a while.) Great course, and many of the topics really closely matched concepts I had already discovered inside MP/M-86 - preemptive task switching, interprocess communication, etc. It felt like someone at DRI had taken the course, though I'm pretty sure that was not the case. While clearly, due to many different limitations, MP/M was not a mainframe class operating system, it certainly covered many of the same concepts, unlike MS/PC-DOS which didn't hit that level until much later. MP/M (in my case MP/M-86) allowed exploring these kinds of things in a practical way that most students couldn't - you only got an ordinary user space on a mainframe as an undergrad.

I would think the OP is asking especially about MP/M for 8 bit systems.

@Raffzahn True, but: 1 - The other answer already moved up to 8086/80286; 2 - Except for "how to handle ill-behaved IBM PC applications" (which showed up much later) I suspect the basic methods are the same for time slicing between MP/M and MP/M-86/CDOS/etc.

60 Hz? Not really. Those are example data to be adapted by a system builder. Keep in mind MP/M was, like CP/M, not sold as end customer system, but to someone adapting that base kit to their hardware by writing a BIOS/XIOS and of course modifying the generator to the values needed for their system.  Time is managed using three flags, Minute, Second and Time_Unit. They are updated by the machine dependent XIOS. The clock process waits for the first two, while the dispatcher uses the third. It is undefined what length a Tine_Unit has. The BIOS guide suggest a value in the range of 60 Hz.

[Flags is a set of 32 semaphores a process can use for synchronisation (aka wait for).  The first few are defined by MP/M for time keeping]

60 Hz is clearly the default by design in at least some versions. Certainly logical to use 50 Hz in 50 Hz AC power areas, and really any value could be used. But as with so many other things, factory defaults = inertia = most common.

Here the description for that field from the Gensys documentation: "Number of Ticks / Second. This value can be used by applications programs to determine the number of ticks per second. This value may vary among MP/M II systems." (Also, I was wrong, only Flag#2 (seconds) is set by XIOS, #3 (minutes) is done by the clock process.)

60 Hz - not really. It's not a factory set default. It's a value the OS provides that programs have an idea how long a delay wait is. This value is XIOS defined, a piece of software written by the system manufacturer (did it mayself a few times). In next to all commercial MP/M systems I know it's driven by a Z80 CTC. The length of that interval is purely defined by how the XIOS programs the CTC and in no way related to AC power. One uses whatever is convenient due CTC and system clock. (I know, some assumptions are easy to make and will hit in 90% of all cases, except here it's a 100% miss).

@Raffzahn As far as number of ticks: (a) while in general there is no need to tie it to local A/C frequency, plenty of systems would do that (and default 60 does that "coincidentally" for US/Canada), (b) if the XIOS is doing ticks at a different rate than the OS-configured/provided value (the byte 122 value that I noted) then things could be a little wacky. But I agree that the XIOS does indeed have to handle programming that tick value somewhere - it won't happen on its own and there is no reliable way to determine that from the Z80 (or 8086 etc.) itself when running - you really need an

external clock of some sort. Of course, MS-DOS famously ended up with an 18.2/second tick, which had some limited logic to it (64k per hour) but when used for multi-tasking was not as smooth as a 60 (or 50) Hz tick.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Actually 64K ticks per hour was accidental and not exact (the actual value is ≈65543.43 ticks per hour). The MS-DOS tick frequency comes from the crystal frequency used in IBM PC (14.31818 MHz, which is 4 times the NTSC colorburst frequency); the PIT clock was OSC/12, and the timer was configured for the maximum possible period — 65536 clocks, which gave ≈18.20651 Hz.
